# Possible for Uber to add car count to /v1/products

Tags: uber-api, availability

I know Uber doesn't want to allow car coordinates for all available cars (not fully certain why though), however, could Uber please at least add the total available cars at any given request time, something like the following:

```
"products": [
    {
       "capacity": 2,
        **"available": 7,**  // add available cars available (or similar)
       "description": "Ride for less with uberPOOL",
       "price_details": {
          "distance_unit": "mile",
          "cost_per_minute": 0.26,
          "service_fees": [
             {
                "fee": 1.0,
                "name": "Safe Rides Fee"
             }
          ],
          "minimum": 5.0,
          "cost_per_distance": 1.3,
          "base": 2.2,
          "cancellation_fee": 5.0,
          "currency_code": "USD"
       },
       "image": "http://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/car.jpg",
       "display_name": "POOL",
       "product_id": "26546650-e557-4a7b-86e7-6a3942445247",
       "shared": true,
    },
```

Showing that a car is available is great, but what if its only one car and someone else snags it before the user viewing it is able to do so?  If it shows "Cars Available: 5" - then the user knows there is a pretty good chance they will get a driver close to the allotted ETA already provided.